# Java8 Method chaining for Single object without Stream/Optional?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, option-type

I felt it easiest to capture my question with the below example. I would like to apply multiple transformations on an object (in this case, they all return same class, Number, but not necessarily). With an Optional (Method 3) or Stream (Method 4), I can use the .map elegantly and legibly. However, when used with a single object, I have to either just make an Optional just to use the .map chaining (with a .get() in the end), or use Stream.of() with a findFirst in the end, which seems like unnecessary work.

[My Preference]: I prefer methods 3 & 4, as they seem better for readability than the pre-java8 options - methods 1 & 2.

[Question]: Is there a better/neater/more preferable/more elegant way of achieving the same than all the methods used here? If not, what method would you use?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Tester {

    static class Number {
        private final int value;

        private Number(final int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }

    private static Number add(final Number number, final int val) {
        return new Number(number.getValue() + val);
    }

    private static Number multiply(final Number number, final int val) {
        return new Number(number.getValue() * val);
    }

    private static Number subtract(final Number number, final int val) {
        return new Number(number.getValue() - val);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Number input = new Number(1);

        System.out.println("output1 = " + method1(input)); // 100
        System.out.println("output2 = " + method2(input)); // 100
        System.out.println("output3 = " + method3(input)); // 100
        System.out.println("output4 = " + method4(input)); // 100

        processAList();
    }

    // Processing an object - Method 1
    private static Number method1(final Number input) {
        return subtract(multiply(add(input, 10), 10), 10);
    }

    // Processing an object - Method 2
    private static Number method2(final Number input) {
        final Number added = add(input, 10);
        final Number multiplied = multiply(added, 10);
        return subtract(multiplied, 10);
    }

    // Processing an object - Method 3 (Contrived use of Optional)
    private static Number method3(final Number input) {
        return Optional.of(input)
            .map(number -> add(number, 10))
            .map(number -> multiply(number, 10))
            .map(number -> subtract(number, 10)).get();
    }

    // Processing an object - Method 4 (Contrived use of Stream)
    private static Number method4(final Number input) {
        return Stream.of(input)
            .map(number -> add(number, 10))
            .map(number -> multiply(number, 10))
            .map(number -> subtract(number, 10))
            .findAny().get();
    }

    // Processing a list (naturally uses the Stream advantage)
    private static void processAList() {
        final List<Number> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        inputs.add(new Number(1));
        inputs.add(new Number(2));

        final List<Number> outputs = inputs.stream()
            .map(number -> add(number, 10))
            .map(number -> multiply(number, 10))
            .map(number -> subtract(number, 10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("outputs = " + outputs); // [100, 110]
    }
}
```

Comment: asking *which method would you use*, well, _is_ opinion based, voting to close it as such

Comment: Why do you think, wrapping these three method invocations with an `Optional` or `Stream` operation does improve the code? All I can see, is that you made the code for the same operation bigger and more complicated.

Comment: It looks a lot more readable when dealing with bigger method/variable names and more number of arguments.. This was a simplified example to illustrate. Method-1 becomes too unreadable too quickly. Method-2 requires creating variables for each additional method in the chain. I do like how neat 3 & 4 look.

Comment: That’s nonsense. Method 3 & 4 create even more variables, just having the same name in your example, which is possible as they have different scopes. But nobody stops you from writing `Number method2(Number number) { number = add(number, 10); number = multiply(number, 10); number = subtract(number, 10); return number; }`, if you think, putting each invocation into a new line makes it more readable. Not that this has much practical relevance, as expressions rarely form such a chain. How do you implement `(a + b) * (c - 2 * d)` here?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. `Optional` is designed mostly for handling nullable values, `Stream` is designed mostly for applying same action on a collection (or combination) of values, however methods 3 & 4 are not covering above cases. Your Method 3 neither improves readability/efficiency nor protects you from nulls (in this particular case). Your Method 4 does actually apply multiple actions to a single (first) value rather than the same action to a collection of values.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to build your methods into your `Number` class. For example:

```
static class Number {
    // instance variable, constructor and getter unchanged

    public Number add(final int val) {
        return new Number(getValue() + val);
    }

    // mulitply() and subtract() in the same way

    // toString() unchanged
}
```

Now your code becomes very simple and readable:

```
private static Number method5(final Number input) {
    return input
        .add(10)
        .multiply(10)
        .subtract(10);
}
```

You may even write the return statement on one line if you prefer:

```
    return input.add(10).multiply(10).subtract(10);
```

**Edit:** If you can't change the `Number` class, my personal taste would be for method2. Using `Optional` or `Stream` would be misuse or at least misplaced and could easily confuse your reader. If you insist, write your own `Mandatory` class, like `Optional` except it always holds a value, which makes it simpler. For my part I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks, but my intent of the question was not about the Number class itself.. it was when I couldn't change the Number class, but had to use it.. If you have to do a bunch of transformations (not necessarily involving the same object, this was for simplicity), we seem to need to create a bunch of temporary variables.. I like the elegance of Method 3 though, where I can just chain the transformations by listing lambdas..

Comment: In that case my personal taste would be for method2. Using `Optional` or `Stream` would be misuse or at least misplaced and could easily confuse your reader. If you insist, write your own `Mandatory` class, like `Optional` except it always holds a value, which makes it simpler. For my part I wouldn't bother.